# node js sql, multple update column didnt change the data

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am trying to update data in mydatabase using Update the code work but the data didnt change

**here is my controller code of the update function**

```
const updateFasilitas = (req, res) => {
  const idFasilitas = req.params.idFasilitas;  
  const idGedung = req.body.idGedung;
    const namaFasilitas = req.body.namaFasilitas;
    const linkTour = req.body.linkTour;
    const penjelasan = req.body.penjelasan;
    
    const sqlQuery = " UPDATE fasilitas SET idGedung = ?, namaFasilitas = ?, linkTour = ?, penjelasan = ? WHERE idFasilitas = ?";
    
    db.query(sqlQuery, [idFasilitas ,idGedung, namaFasilitas, linkTour,penjelasan], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
};
```

**here is my route code**

```
router.put('/fasilitas/update/:idFasilitas', ctrl.updateFasilitas);
```

**and the index**

```
const { db } = require('./db');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const sessions = require('express-session');
const app = express();
const fasilitasroute = require ('./fasilitasroute');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(fasilitasroute);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server berhasil berjalan pada port 3000!');
  });
```

i did try change the route to post but it didnt work as well. and the sql code i did try change by following some answer in this site from another question closely as me but it didnt work.
any idea how this happen?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Check the parameters which are passed to query() method. `idFasilitas` is the first parameter, while it's used as last parameter in SQL statement.